# How do I turn FTP sharing on in Lion?

Tags: macos, sharing, file-sharing, ftp

I recently upgraded to Lion and I tried to FTP into it from another Mac, but I couldn't. I went to System Preferences>Sharing and could only find AFP and SMB sharing. How do I enable FTP sharing in Lion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option has been removed from the GUI in OS X 10.7 however you can enable it with a few commands.

Here is a good write up on how to do it.

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20088844-263/managing-ftp-services-in-os-x-lion/

Summary of the link above:

To Load:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

Then to start and stop you would run the following:

```
sudo launchctl start com.apple.ftpd

sudo launchctl stop com.apple.ftpd
```

To Unload:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Can you please summarize the contents of the link? Links have a tendency to disappear down the road, leaving other people with an answer that has no meaning, because the link doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: I'd agree with the link above by enabling remote login for SFTP access. I will summarise the enable ftp above anywho.

Answer (score 6):

If I am not mistaken FTP is not supported anymore, [too insecure, eg sends your password in the clear over the network etc](http://www.interwork.com/blog/2008/11/18/qa-how-to-eliminate-the-security-risks-associated-with-telnet-ftp/). However, if you enable "Remote Login" in sharing, you can use SFTP which works just as well as FTP. [SFTP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sftp.1.html) stands for secure FTP and therefore all the information you transfer between computers is encrypted while in transit over the network, internet, etc.

[image: Remote Login enable]

Once you enable it on your computer you can connect to it using SSH / [SFTP log in formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sftp.1.html) for example see below:

```
sftp username@hostname_or_ip-address
```

Comment: I was using a GUI app and I tried SFTP as the protocol, but it wouldn't connect. I *do* have Remote Login enabled.

Comment: Check the Firewall setting in "Security & Privacy" system prefernce pane, you may want to temporary turn off the firewall and then see if you can connect.

Comment: My Firewall is off.

Comment: What's the difference when you run the `sftp user@host` vs `ssh user@host`? If you can ssh in you should be able to sftp in. Does this other solution help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/create-a-remote-only-user-in-os-x/

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I know the differences. I was asking if you can log in via sftp in the Terminal? When logging in via sftp your should get an `sftp > ` prompt.

Comment: afragen: Yes thats correct you can can log in via the terminal and get the "sftp>" prompt. You can even sftp locally on the the computer you just enabled Remote Login on, you don't need to connect from a different mac / computer.

Comment: I'm just trying to ask whether @daviesgeek can do this. I agree with your solution, even upvoted, just wondering if there's a problem with the GUI app he's using.

Comment: daviesgeek: try connecting to your mac while on it. On the same mac you enabled Remote Login on, open terminal and try the noted sftp command filling in your ip and your account user name, it should contain no spaces. Try the whoami command from the terminal to get your user name.

Comment: I tried that and I get: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed` That's the same sort of error I got when connecting via the GUI app.

Comment: Does this link help? http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/06/msg02345.html or adding `#/etc/hosts.allow
sshd:LOCAL
sshd:192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0`

Comment: Try make a copy of the .ssh directory in your home folder to a different name, then delete .ssh directory.   Then try again you should get a question do you want to trust the remote host. Reply yes.

Comment: @MrDaniel I tried that, same error.

Comment: @afragen There isn't a file called `hosts.allow` under `/etc`

Comment: @daviesgeek It's probably the `/etc/hosts` file. Differences likely based on linux system that the reference comes from.

Comment: @daviesgeek Can you `ping` the machine you're trying to access. Just curious.

Comment: @daviesgeek Do you have a folder `/var/empty`? If not create it and `sudo chown -R root:sys` then reboot and see what happens. Also, happens shows up in system.log when you get this error?

Comment: @afragen Ok, changed it. I still have the same issue. I haven't tried your last comment yet, but I will tomorrow sometime. I have a folder `/var/empty`...