# How to setup FTP server in Mac OS X Lion Server?

Tags: macos, server.app, ftp

I found that there isn't any FTP options in Lion Server. How can I setup it up? I would like to restrict .....

1. Which user can login with FTP server?
2. Which folder can permitted user access?

I found that I can install vsftpd via homebrew, but I can't find the vsftpd.conf file...

Would anyone here kindly tell me how to do these? Thank a lot.

Comment: Setting up SFTP instead of FTP might be a better choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn FTP sharing on in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43806/how-do-i-turn-ftp-sharing-on-in-lion)

Comment: Thanks Hippo. But How can I restrict the permission for different folder?

Comment: Hi daviesgeek. Sorry, I just find this questions. But I would like to know more on how to setup user permission. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @siulamvictor: I believe that normal UNIX permissions will apply, regardless of whether the user is accessing the system remotely (using SSH) or not.

Comment: We can take this question in two directions - looking for info to fully integrate ftpd with Lion users and groups or what non-integrated ftpd packages are easy to compile on lion server. Both are on topic here, but if @siulamvictor wants both answers, two questions would be better than trying to get both addressed in one shot.

Comment: I think the answer is same as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/create-a-remote-only-user-in-os-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the answer at [Create a Remote Only User in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/create-a-remote-only-user-in-os-x/).

The last part of that post will use `bindfs` to mount a user privileged only folder. See below. The whole instruction set is on the blog post referenced or just look at both posts. If someone wants me to duplicate that other post here let me know.

Getting in is one thing. Now you have to mount the folder you want to use. Unfortunately you can't use a symlink inside of a chroot jail. This is where [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) is your best friend. I don't know why I've never seen fit to install this before. After installation just issue the following commands.

```
sudo port install fuse4x
sudo port install fuse4x bindfs
```

You might have to restart. Now with an empty folder created in `/chroot/user` you can `mount --bind` to a folder outside of the chroot jail. For example

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/bindfs -u user /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/yourfolder /chroot/user/scratchpad
```

So far this seems to work here.